# Overlay video at specific point relative to the end of a source video in FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg

This command works correctly for overlaying the second input (PNG sequence) at an arbitrary point of time from the start of the first input (test-video.mp4), for example, at 3 seconds

```
ffmpeg -i test-video.mp4 -itsoffset 3 -i outro-frames/Outro.%05d.png -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref[scaled][ref];[ref][scaled]overlay=x=0:y=0:enable=gt(t\,3\)" test-video-outro.mp4
```

But what I’m trying to do is instead of displaying this 3 seconds from the start to display it 3 seconds from the end (ie the length of test-video.mp4 - 3 seconds).

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: So you want to overlay the last three seconds on the first three seconds?

Comment: No, I’d like to overlay the outro-frames sequence (2nd input) 3 seconds from the end of the test-video.mp4 (1st input), not 3 seconds from the beginning. Does that make sense now? Thanks.